# CORS issue with accessing AWS API Gateway -> Lambda from simple js fetch

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors

I'm aware there's a number of questions over here to do with this exact situation but I can't get any of them to work. Here's the situation and my attempts to fix it:

I've got a node js lambda sitting behind an API Gateway in AWS. Works with POSTman but on a simple HTML + JS website, gives me this CORS error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://......' from origin 'https://......' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

What I've tried

- I've created a function url for the lambda to remove the complexity of the API gateway as a test.
- Added an OPTIONS http request handler which works and I can see it in the network tab. The options handler also has the above headers
- Added the following CORS headers to the output and I can see them in the response from POSTman:

```
      "Content-Type":"application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
    }
```

[image: POSTman response with CORS headers]

Comment: Apologies if the Web Console is inaccessible. I've solved a similar problem by going to Console > API Gateway > {your api} > (Left-hand side) Develop > CORS > and configuring it there. It had less to do with my request rather than API Gateway blocking it.

Comment: Thanks @it'sjayway, I'm using the public function url for the lambda to eliminate the API gateway as a possible cause and still facing the issue